# Perl print output file names with number variable

Tags: sql, perl, variables, fetch, filehandler

I am trying to pull 1 week data from sql server, then trying to write the data into files with separate names.
Following codes does not work, and I cannot find a way to create file handlers with a variable.

Another question is that if the size of sql data is huge (1-2 gigabyte per day, and the entire table is over 1 year period), then is this monthly fetching method is faster than daily fetching?

```
    my $sqlGetEid = "select trunc(datetime, 'DD') truncdate, x, y from z
        where DATETIME between TO_DATE('$dt1','YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE('$dt1','YYYY-MM-DD')+7";

    for ($day=1; $day<=7; $day++){
        open('dayfile_$day', "> ./temp/Wireless_$day.csv");  
    }

    while ( my ($tday,$x,$y) = $curSqlEid->fetchrow_array() ) 
    {
        printf {'dayfile_$tday'} ("%s,%d\n", $x,$y);
    }

    for ($day=1; $day<=7; $day++){
        close('dayfile_$day');  
    }
```

Comment: FYI, the single quotes in `'dayfile_$day` will prevent interpolation of the variable `$day`. Besides it being invalid file handles, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use plain strings as variables like you're trying to do.

The simplest way I can think of for this is to use a hash to map file names with filehandles.

Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %files;

foreach my $i (1..7) {
    my $fh;
    open($fh, '>', "day_$i.log") || die "Ooups: $i: $!";
    $files{$i} = $fh;
}

foreach my $i (1..7) {
    my $fh = $files{$i};
    print $fh "hello $i\n";
}

foreach my $i (1..7) {
    my $fh = $files{$i};
    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: Another solution is to ORDER BY the day, then reopen the file handle when the day for one row is different than the day for the previous row.

Comment: Ahh, yes. I'll admit I didn't even think about trying to avoid the whole thing. I guess there _might_ be a performance aspect to doing it without the `order by`.

Comment: Shouldn't be any real performance difference. It might just be a bit simpler to read, and it's a bit more scalable. (Processes have a limited number of files handles at their disposal. While it's more than 7, it's possible to hit the max.) Either would do fine here.